# luaoftload v3.17 with HarfBuzz does awful line breaking with Garamond

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, luaotfload, garamond, harftex

I have this long document which I've been maintaining for years now, which I use Adobe's Garamond Premier Pro font for typesetting, and the whole document is fine-tuned to avoid overfull boxes and such (so I can't easily change fonts). Since the last `luaotfload` update, the whole document got completely messed up regarding line breaking. Took me some time to narrow down the issue to this example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[17]
\end{document}
```

And the problem requires that specific combination to show up. If I change `11pt` to `10pt`, line breaking looks right. If I remove `Renderer=HarfBuzz`, line breaking looks right.  If I change the font to, say, `EB Garamond`, line breaking looks right (or any font, in fact. I could only reproduce the problem with Garamond Premier Pro). Depending on the language I use (with `babel`), line breaking looks slightly better, but still off.

If I downgrade `luaotfload` to v3.15 (with `tlmgr restore luaotfload 56269`), line breaking looks great:

[image]

But if I update it again to v3.17 (with `tlmgr update luaotfload`), line breaking is a wreck:

[image]

What's going on? Is Garamond Premier Pro no longer supported by `luaotfload`?

P.S.: Sorry for requiring a commercial font in this question, but I really could not reproduce the problem with another font (I tried a few, but all worked correctly).

Comment: This isn’t part of your specific question, but `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and `\usepackage{microtype}` can generally improve hyphenation. Since you say changing from `Renderer=HarfBuzz` to `Renderer=Node` fixes the problem, is that a good workaround?

Comment: Open an issue at the luaotfload github.

Comment: @Davislor Well, it does, but it also changes break points in my document, and I would _love_ to avoid that if possible.  In hindsight, maybe it was stupid to use HarfBuzz if I don't need it, but now I'm all in, so... tough

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/175. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hyphenation with Harfbuzz was (is?) somewhat buggy (see https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/152 ). I'm not sure if it has been fixed, but in LGR scripts the recommended renderer is the default one.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks for that link.  It contain lots of useful information.  I find two things particularly curious: 1) in the example picture it chooses to keep two words, `varius quis` together, even if the line break is visibly better between them, and 2) it worked well in v3.15, so it seems a bit like a regression (so much so that Ulrike Fischer, who seems to be one of the authors of `luaotfload`, asked for a issue report).  Anyway, your comment is very useful (in the end I think I'll have to switch to the default renderer and rework my line breaks... that won't be fun...), so thanks!